# If tag x then show y + tag name(s)

Tags: tags

I would like to have on my `single.php`:

*Tag: Tag1*

Or if more than one Tag:

*Tags: Tag1, Tag2*

The `Tag1` and `Tag2` should link to a custom URL.

I found this, but don't know how to get exactly what I want.

```
if( has_tag() ) {
    // somehow echo "Tags" + Tagnames with custom links seperated by commas.
}
else{
        // show nothing
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add some code and more description to make it more understandable. Otherwise it's hard for us to get the real scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `get_the_tags` function, something along the lines of:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    echo (count($posttags) > 1) ? 'Tags: ' : 'Tag: ';
    $links = array();
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $links[] = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',  get_tag_link($tag->term_id), $tag->name);
    }
    echo implode(', ', $links);
}
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks. - Would like to have separators like a comma between multiple tags. How do I do that?

Comment: Just modify the sprintf template to `'<a href="%s">%s</a>, '`

Comment: Thanks! But if there is only one tag, I'll get "Tag1," - with many tags this is fine.

Comment: You're right, i'll update answer